# how to overwrite the file with map contents in cpp

Tags: c++, file, containers, fwrite

I'm trying to overwrite my text file with map contents, can anyone give me the idea on that
upto to now i did

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, string> mymap;

    mymap[34] = "hero";
    mymap[74] = "Clarie";
    mymap[13] = "Devil";

    for( map<int,string>::iterator i=mymap.begin(); i!=mymap.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << (*i).first << ":" << (*i).second << endl;
    }

    // write the map contents to file .
    // mymap &Emp;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("bigfile.txt","w");
    if(fp!=NULL)
    {
        for(map<int,string>::iterator it =mymap.begin();it!=mymap.end();++it)
        {
            fwrite(&mymap,1,sizeof(&mymap),fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

I'm new to containers. Am i in correct procedure and while writing the map contents to file it is giving me garbage content in file.
thanks in advance

Comment: You can't serialize complex object directly to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your problem:

Your call to [`fwrite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) is pretty broken.

`fwrite()` will write a series of bytes to the given file. For example, if we wanted to write an `int` to the file, we would need to do something like:

```
int x = 10;
char text[10];
snprintf(text, 10, "%d", x);
fwrite(text, 1, strlen(text), fp);
```

And for a `std::string`, we would need to do something like:

```
std::string y = "Hello";
fwrite(y.c_str(), 1, y.size(), fp);
```

Alternatively, you could use `fprintf()`:

```
int x = 10;
std::string y = "Hello";
fprintf(fp, "%d:%s\n", x, y.c_str());
```

#### Let's use a C++ tool instead of a C tool:

If we use C++'s [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), then things are much simpler. In fact, the code will look almost identical to how we use `std::cout`.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    map<int, string> mymap;

    mymap[34] = "hero";
    mymap[74] = "Clarie";
    mymap[13] = "Devil";

    for(map<int,string>::iterator i=mymap.begin(); i!=mymap.end(); ++i)
        cout << i->first << ":" << i->second << "\n";

    // write the map contents to file.
    std::ofstream output("bigfile.txt");
    assert(output.good());

    for(map<int,string>::iterator it =mymap.begin();it!=mymap.end();++it)
        output << it->first << ":" << it->second << "\n";
}
```

This will output to the screen and write to `bigfile.txt` this:

```
13:Devil
34:hero
74:Clarie
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Bill, could you explain me how to perform the same thing using C.

Comment: can i do the same thing in C without storing the map content into a buf.

Comment: @Kiran: You could use `fprintf()` which I've added an example showing. But I'd strongly recommend that you use C++ tools when writing C++ code instead of using the c compatibility functions.

Comment: No, i think fprintf() is not a better idea for overwriting the file compare to fwrite() and we can't use fprintf for overwriting a big file.